# give random css syle by jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to give each of my `div` tags random back colors using this code. But it sets all `div` tags to one background color. I want them to be different. It used to work properly, but something happened and it does not work right now:

```js
var downcolors = ["#ff7043", "#8d6e63", "#ffa726", "#ffca28", "#66bb6a", "#9ccc65", "#d4e157", "#29b6f6", "#26c6da", "#26a69a", "#4db6ac", "#4dd0e1", "#4fc3f7", "#009688", "#7e57c2", "#5c6bc0", "#42a5f5", "#ef5350", "#ec407a", "#ab47bc"];
var topcolors = ["#d84315", "#37474f", "#455a64", "#d84315", "#bf360c", "#3e2723", "#4e342e", "#5d4037", "#212121", "#424242", "#1b5e20", "#33691e", "#827717", "#01579b", "#006064", "#004d40", "#6200ea", "#311b92", "#1a237e", "#0d47a1", "#4527a0", "#283593", "#b71c1c", "#880e4f", "#4a148c"];
var downrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * downcolors.length);
var toprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * topcolors.length);

$.each($(".tg-item-inner"), function(idx, elem) {
  $(elem).css({
    'background': 'linear-gradient(to top, ' + downcolors[downrand] + ' 50%, ' + topcolors[toprand] + ' 50%)'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the random variables each time you loop through, ie inside the loop rather than outside:

```js
var downcolors = ["#ff7043", "#8d6e63", "#ffa726", "#ffca28", "#66bb6a", "#9ccc65", "#d4e157", "#29b6f6", "#26c6da", "#26a69a", "#4db6ac", "#4dd0e1", "#4fc3f7", "#009688", "#7e57c2", "#5c6bc0", "#42a5f5", "#ef5350", "#ec407a", "#ab47bc"];
var topcolors = ["#d84315", "#37474f", "#455a64", "#d84315", "#bf360c", "#3e2723", "#4e342e", "#5d4037", "#212121", "#424242", "#1b5e20", "#33691e", "#827717", "#01579b", "#006064", "#004d40", "#6200ea", "#311b92", "#1a237e", "#0d47a1", "#4527a0", "#283593", "#b71c1c", "#880e4f", "#4a148c"];

$.each($("div"), function(idx, elem) {
  // move random variables to inside the loop
  var downrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * downcolors.length);
  var toprand = Math.floor(Math.random() * topcolors.length);
  $(elem).css({
    'background': 'linear-gradient(to top, ' + downcolors[downrand] + ' 50%, ' + topcolors[toprand] + ' 50%)'
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```